# how to insert limited record into mysql using php

Tags: php

Is there any way to registered limited users. mean that i registered 10 user using insert Query. now i want to check if there is 10 users registered in the database. stop registering more Users.  and display message Sorry we can't create your account  10 users already registered.

```
<?php
require('connection.php');
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
    {

            $user_name = $_POST['username'];
            $father_name = $_POST['fname'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $confirm_password = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
            if($password==$confirm_password){
            $insert = mysql_query("insert into user values('','$user_name','$father_name','$password','$confirm_password')");
            }
            else
            {
                $passwordmsg = "Password Must Be Matched";
            }
            if($insert)
            {
                $msg = "Registration Succesfull";   
            }
            else
            {
                $msg = "Registration failled please Try Again Later !";
            }

    }
?>
```

Comment: There are multiple ways. What options have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Dainis Abols i tried mysql_num_rows to count the record but its not working

Comment: Ouch, ever heard of [SQL Injections](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require('connection.php');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $str_sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user");
    $int_rows = mysql_num_rows($str_sql);
    if ($int_rows < 10) {
        $user_name = $_POST['username'];
        $father_name = $_POST['fname'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $confirm_password = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
        if ($password == $confirm_password) {
            $insert = mysql_query("insert into user values('','$user_name','$father_name','$password','$confirm_password')");
        } else {
            $passwordmsg = "Password Must Be Matched";
        }
        if ($insert) {
            $msg = "Registration Succesfull";
        } else {
            $msg = "Registration failled please Try Again Later !";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Khan : did you try it?

Comment: @Khan: What are you doing ? You have accepted three answer? accept one only answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Before you insert a new user, check for the number of users using select command and return the number of rows. if number of rows is greater then 10, then display your message.
A simple if condition would solve your problem.

```
<?php
 require('connection.php');
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
  {
    $no_of_rows = mysql_query("count(*) FROM user");

    if($no_of_rows <10){
    $user_name = $_POST['username'];
    $father_name = $_POST['fname'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $confirm_password = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
    if($password==$confirm_password){
    $insert = mysql_query("insert into user          values('','$user_name','$father_name','$password','$confirm_password')");
    }
    else
    {
        $passwordmsg = "Password Must Be Matched";
    }
    if($insert)
    {
        $msg = "Registration Succesfull";   
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = "Registration failled please Try Again Later !";
    }
  }
  else{
    $msg = "Number of users reached limit. Please try again later!"
   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Write the code please...!

Comment: Thanks Amith Raj Shetty

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user, $password, $database);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error." [$sql]"); 
if($result->num_rows == 10) {
   //no more users can be registered
} else {
   //insert and register new user
}
$mysqli->close() ;
```

Go through the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Thanks Criesto for help